# Error: Invalid options specification: options.staging.type

Tags: juju

I am following the instruction in http://jujucharms.com/~juju-gui/precise/juju-gui but I am getting the following error. It looks like a string is exepect where a boolean is defined.

```
$> juju deploy cs:~juju-gui/precise/juju-gui

Invalid options specification: options.staging.type: expected 'string', got 'boolean' 2013-02-11 19:31:37,896 ERROR Invalid options specification: options.staging.type: expected 'string', got 'boolean'
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The charm you're looking at isn't the recommended one for juju gui. It's used for development, and you're welcome to investigate it, but it's usually not going to be the one you want to try.

You can read about the recommended charm for the gui at [jujucharms.com/precise/juju-gui](https://jujucharms.com/precise/juju-gui). To deploy it, you can just do

```
juju deploy juju-gui
```

As a side note, you can easily see when a charm is the recommended one or not by looking for the orange marks in the upper right hand corner of search results and detail views. You can see an example of what I mean here:

[image]

Not all charms have a recommended version, but you should usually look for recommended ones first unless you have a particular reason to look for another version.

Comment: a question asked a year ago answered today! I know that the answer will help future users, I just hope that the person who asked the question is still alive :)